# How would I get this program to calculate the total from 5 TextView values?

Tags: android, spinner

I am trying to get my program to properly display the total amount of calories once a user selects food names from drop down boxes. It will display the amount of calories from each food name to the right. However, at the bottom once the total button is clicked, I want it to display the amount in a textview area. Right now when I click on the total button, the whole app crashes (no error message given). Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I feel like there is a better way to do what I want to do, but the method that I have implemented is the only way that I know how. Can't seem to find anything else online. My code:

```
public class CalorieTracker extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    TextView sp1;
    TextView sp2;
    TextView sp3;
    TextView sp4;
    TextView sp5;
    Spinner spinner1;
    Spinner spinner2;
    Spinner spinner3;
    Spinner spinner4;
    Spinner spinner5;
    int total;
    TextView caloriesNum;
    List<String> foods = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> calories = new ArrayList<String>();

    int Cal1;
    int Cal2;
    int Cal3;
    int Cal4;
    int Cal5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calorie_tracker);

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        spinner4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
        spinner5 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner5);

        sp1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spinner1TextView);
        sp2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spinner2TextView);
        sp3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spinner3TextView);
        sp4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spinner4TextView);
        sp5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spinner5TextView);
        caloriesNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.caloriesNumbers);

        populateSpinner();
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.foods_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner4.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner5.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    public void populateSpinner() {
        foods.add("");
        foods.add("Chicken");
        foods.add("Pizza");
        foods.add("Eggs");
        foods.add("Spaghetti");
        foods.add("Salad");
        foods.add("Ice Cream");
        foods.add("Bacon");
        foods.add("Banana");
        foods.add("Bagel");
        foods.add("Beef Roast");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, foods);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner3.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner4.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner5.setAdapter(adapter);

        calories.add("0");
        calories.add("300");
        calories.add("365");
        calories.add("70");
        calories.add("325");
        calories.add("105");
        calories.add("340");
        calories.add("90");
        calories.add("60");
        calories.add("75");
        calories.add("315");
    }

    public void addCalories(View v) {
        Cal1 = Integer.parseInt(sp1.getText().toString());
        Cal2 = Integer.parseInt(sp2.getText().toString());
        Cal3 = Integer.parseInt(sp3.getText().toString());
        Cal4 = Integer.parseInt(sp4.getText().toString());
        Cal5 = Integer.parseInt(sp5.getText().toString());

        total = Cal1 + Cal2 + Cal3 + Cal4 + Cal5;
        caloriesNum.setText(total);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present. 
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_calorie_tracker, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch (parent.getId()) {
            case R.id.spinner1:
                String strCal1 = calories.get(position).toString();
                sp1.setText(strCal1);
                break;
            case R.id.spinner2:
                String strCal2 = calories.get(position).toString();
                sp2.setText(strCal2);
                break;
            case R.id.spinner3:
                String strCal3 = calories.get(position).toString();
                sp3.setText(strCal3);
                break;
            case R.id.spinner4:
                String strCal4 = calories.get(position).toString();
                sp4.setText(strCal4);
                break;
            case R.id.spinner5:
                String strCal5 = calories.get(position).toString();
                sp5.setText(strCal5);
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
}
```

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save"
    android:id="@+id/saveButton"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/backButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="#ff00cc27" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Back"
    android:id="@+id/backButton"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/saveButton"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/saveButton" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Total Calories:"
    android:id="@+id/totalCaloriesTextView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/saveButton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/saveButton"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/saveButton" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="0"
    android:id="@+id/caloriesNumbers"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/totalCaloriesTextView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/totalCaloriesTextView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/totalCaloriesTextView" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Total"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:onClick="addCalories"
    android:id="@+id/totalButton"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/backButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/backButton"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/backButton" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Calories"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner1TextView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/totalButton"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/totalButton" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Calories"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner2TextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1TextView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner1TextView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner1TextView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Calories"
    android:id="@+id/spinner3TextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2TextView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner2TextView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner2TextView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Calories"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/spinner4TextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner3TextView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner3TextView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner3TextView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Calories"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner5TextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner4TextView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner4TextView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner4TextView" />
```

LogCat:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x384
            at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:274)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4122)
            at buckystutorial.foodsspinneritems.CalorieTracker.addCalories(CalorieTracker.java:127)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you are missing *View* parameter in yours *addCalories* method. Please provide the stacktrace which is dumped into logcat.

Comment: @Cativail Ok I entered your suggestion, and I tried to run it, but this is the error message that is output

Answer (score 0):

Change method's signature from

```
public void addCalories()
```

to

```
public void addCalories(View v)
```

Also, it is very important to understand why you can't read logcat - you will not be able to proceed in a normal way without it.

Comment: I entered your suggestion but I am still having an issue. The error message is provided from the logcat

Comment: Change caloriesNum.setText(total); to caloriesNum.setText(String.valueOf(total));